# Moving a batch variable to a sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, batch-file, sqlcommand

Is there anyway to take the output of a batch variable and put it into a SQL table?

For example, if I'm calculating the time it takes for a script to execute

```
set STARTTIME=%time%
code to be measured
set ENDTIME=%time%
set /a DURATION=%STARTTIME%-%ENDTIME%
echo %DURATION%
```

could I take the `%DURATION%` variable and put that into a sql table on sql server

EDIT: This is my batch script

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cls

RMDIR c:\path1 /s /q
mkdir c:\path1
xcopy "\\path2\*" c:\path1 /s /i
cd c:\path3

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od') do set newest=%%a
cd c:\path1

sqlcmd -S server -i "\\path2\DropDatabases.sql"

for /D /r %%F IN ("*") DO ( 
    for %%G  IN ("%%F\*.extenstion1") DO xcopy "%%G" c:\path2\%newest% /y /i

        set STARTTIME=!TIME!

    for /f "delims=_" %%J IN ('forfiles /p "%%F" /m *.jmpt /c "cmd /c echo @path"')  DO start "program"  /D "c:\path3" /Wait program -r  %%J

    set ENDTIME=!TIME!
call :GetDuration !STARTTIME! !ENDTIME! 
    )
)

    exit /b
    :GetDuration
    set function_starttime=%1
    set function_endtime=%2

    rem Change formatting for the start and end times
    for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%function_starttime%") do (
        set /A "start=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
)

    for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%function_endtime%") do (
        set /A "end=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
)

    rem Calculate the elapsed time by subtracting values
    set /A elapsed=end-start

    rem Format the results for output
    set /A hh=elapsed/(60*60*100), rest=elapsed%%(60*60*100), mm=rest/(60*100), rest%%=60*100, ss=rest/100, cc=rest%%100
    if %hh% lss 10 set hh=0%hh%
    if %mm% lss 10 set mm=0%mm%
    if %ss% lss 10 set ss=0%ss%
    if %cc% lss 10 set cc=0%cc%

    set DURATION=%hh%:%mm%:%ss%.%cc%

    echo Start    : %function_starttime%
    echo Finish   : %function_endtime%
    echo          ---------------
    echo Duration : %DURATION%
    echo.

sqlcmd -S server -i "\\path2\query.sql" rem **This is the query shown below**

pause
```

EDIT: This is the query

```
declare @dbname nvarchar (200);
declare @query nvarchar (max);
declare @testid int;

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
select name from sys.databases
where name like '%abcdbase%' 

select  @testid = coalesce(MAX(TestNum), 0) from [database].table3 
set @testid = @testid + 1;

Open db_cursor
fetch next from db_cursor into @dbname

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
  set @query = CAST('select (select column1 from [' +@dbname+ '].table1 where column2 = ''File Name'') as File_Name, 
            (select column1 from [' +@dbname+ '].table1 where column2 = ''Version'') as Version, 
            CAST(count(*) as float)/MAX(repnum) as Value, column3 as Measure, GETDATE() as DateRun, (select ' + CAST(@testid as CHAR) +') as TestNum from [' +@dbname+ '].table2 
            group by column3  

            union

            select (select column1 from [' +@dbname+ '].table1 where column2 = ''File Name'') as File_Name, 
           (select column1 from [' +@dbname+ '].table1 where column2 = ''Version'') as Version,
            CAST(LEFT((select column1 from [' +@dbname+ '].table1 where column2 = ''File Execution Elapsed Time''), 
            CHARINDEX(''m'',(select column1 from [' +@dbname+ '].table1 where column2 = ''File Execution Elapsed Time''),1 )-2) as float) as  Value, 
           (select ''Run Time'') as Measure, GETDATE() as DateRun, (select ' + CAST(@testid as CHAR) +') as TestNum  from [' +@dbname+ '].table2
            group by column3

            union

            select (select column1 from [' +@dbname+ '].table1 where column2 = ''File Name'') as File_Name, 
           (select column1 from [' +@dbname+ '].table1 where column2 = ''Version'') as Version,
           (SELECT cast((size*8)/1024 as float) SizeMB FROM sys.master_files
            where DB_NAME(database_id) = ''' +@dbname+ ''' and type = 0) as  Value, 
           (select ''DBSize'') as Measure, GETDATE() as DateRun, (select ' + CAST(@testid as CHAR) +') as TestNum  from [' +@dbname+ '].table2
            group by column3

            union

            select (select column1 from [' +@dbname+ '].table1 where column2 = ''File Name'') as File_Name, 
            (select column1 from [' +@dbname+ '].table1 where column2 = ''Version'') as Version, 
            COALESCE(CAST(count(*) as float)/MAX(repnum),0) as Value, ''Total'' as Measure, 
            GETDATE() as DateRun, (select ' + CAST(@testid as CHAR) +') as TestNum 
            from [' +@dbname+ '].table2
            where column3 = ''entry1'' or column3 = ''entry2'' or column3 = ''entry3''' as nvarchar(max))



  Insert INTO [database].table3(File_Name,Version, Value, Measure, DateRun, TestNum)
  Execute (@query)
  FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname 

END
Close db_cursor
deallocate db_cursor
```

Comment: I'd imagine so, with a VBScript / JScript ADODB object of some sort.

Comment: If I tried hard enough I could probably do it.  What's the part causing you difficulty?

Comment: Well I've already got a batch file I'm working with and I would just like to add in a line. The part that's giving me trouble is I don't really know a ton about how the sqlcmd works. I've seen [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) but i'm still not sure how I could use it to take the results of a variable in the batch file and insert it into a specific table. Lets say that I've got other sqlcmd statements in the script that are dropping stuff into specific tables already, can I add in a line that will take the value of the batch variable and add it into the table?

Comment: I'll post an edit with how my code looks. I'll also show the query I'm using currently

Comment: Is the sql server and the batch file running on the same server?

Comment: Yes to the first and second

Answer (score 0):

Nice one...

Can you give this a try....

```
sqlcmd -S <SERVER> -d <DATABASE> -Q "INSERT INTO _DEBUG(Value) Values('%DURATION%')"
```

You'll need to replace the tags with actual values.
i.e.  = server
 = MyDb or You could remove the -d  and prefix the table in your insert statement.
You'll obviously have to replace the insert statement too, with the statement you want to run

If your table is called table2, and it has the following columns... RunDate, Duration,

```
CREATE TABLE Table2(
    RunDate DATETIME NULL,
    Duration VARCHAR(20) NULL);
```

Your insert statement will look like this

```
INSERT INTO Table2(RunDate, Duration) VALUES(GETDATE(), '%DURATION%')
```

That will insert todays date, and the value of %DURATION% into the table called Table2

Hope that helps

Comment: so like "insert into _DEBUG(table2) Values('%DURATION%')"?

Comment: No. _DEBUG is a table in my test database. You'll want something like this.... "INSERT INTO table2(Value) Values('%DURATION%')". assuming table2 has a column called Value and can contain a string.

Comment: so value is a column and "Values" in Values('%DURATION%') is a command?

Comment: yes I think I can figure out the rest! thanks You've been a huge help. I'll comment if there are any more confusions.